# How to get json path for the special character such as @odata.nextLink":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

In Pentaho Spoon, I am trying to build the transformation which will read the Data from Azure AD, and then I will push this data to another application.

Now the problem I am facing is with pagination and I am unable to retrieve the next URL variable from the first REST call.

**In the first REST call, I can see the body like below:**

```
{"@odata.context":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users","@odata.nextLink":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/?$skiptoken=RFNwdAIAAQAAACg6YWJkdWxsYWgucmFzaGVlZGlAYWR2YW5jZWRwZXRyb2NoZW0uY29tKVVzZXJfNDcwMGFmNGEtMjliMi00M2ZjLThlOWYtYzk3MGNkMTM5NTIzuQAAAAAAAAAAAAA","value":[{"id":"34543".......................}]}
```

The actual problem starts here, in the Pentaho transformation I used Json input to extract the next URL with the path below paths (tried with all the below paths.)

```
${@odata.nextLink} OR $.{@odata.nextLink} OR $..{@odata.nextLink} OR $@odata.nextLink
```

But unfortunately, nothing is working.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled across this post while googling how to get @odata.count from another API. Because I didn't find a searchable answer I had to look it up in some old jobs where I hade solved it.

So I post the answer here for me in the future or anyone else looking.
You get it with bracket-notation - ['@odata.nextLink']

Pastable test below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<transformation-steps>
<steps>
  <step>
    <name>Generate rows</name>
    <type>RowGenerator</type>
    <description/>
    <distribute>Y</distribute>
    <custom_distribution/>
    <copies>1</copies>
    <partitioning>
      <method>none</method>
      <schema_name/>
    </partitioning>
    <fields>
      <field>
        <name>json</name>
        <type>String</type>
        <format/>
        <currency/>
        <decimal/>
        <group/>
        <nullif>{&#34;@odata.context&#34;:&#34;https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users&#34;,&#34;@odata.nextLink&#34;:&#34;https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/?$skiptoken=RFNwdAIAAQAAACg6YWJkdWxsYWgucmFzaGVlZGlAYWR2YW5jZWRwZXRyb2NoZW0uY29tKVVzZXJfNDcwMGFmNGEtMjliMi00M2ZjLThlOWYtYzk3MGNkMTM5NTIzuQAAAAAAAAAAAAA&#34;,&#34;value&#34;:[{&#34;id&#34;:&#34;34543&#34;}]}</nullif>
        <length>-1</length>
        <precision>-1</precision>
        <set_empty_string>N</set_empty_string>
      </field>
    </fields>
    <limit>1</limit>
    <never_ending>N</never_ending>
    <interval_in_ms>5000</interval_in_ms>
    <row_time_field>now</row_time_field>
    <last_time_field>FiveSecondsAgo</last_time_field>
<attributes></attributes>
    <cluster_schema/>
    <remotesteps>
      <input>
      </input>
      <output>
      </output>
    </remotesteps>
    <GUI>
      <xloc>294</xloc>
      <yloc>175</yloc>
      <draw>Y</draw>
    </GUI>
    </step>

  <step>
    <name>JSON input</name>
    <type>JsonInput</type>
    <description/>
    <distribute>Y</distribute>
    <custom_distribution/>
    <copies>1</copies>
    <partitioning>
      <method>none</method>
      <schema_name/>
    </partitioning>
    <include>N</include>
    <include_field/>
    <rownum>N</rownum>
    <addresultfile>N</addresultfile>
    <readurl>N</readurl>
    <removeSourceField>N</removeSourceField>
    <IsIgnoreEmptyFile>N</IsIgnoreEmptyFile>
    <doNotFailIfNoFile>Y</doNotFailIfNoFile>
    <ignoreMissingPath>Y</ignoreMissingPath>
    <defaultPathLeafToNull>Y</defaultPathLeafToNull>
    <includeNulls>N</includeNulls>
    <rownum_field/>
    <file>
      <name/>
      <filemask/>
      <exclude_filemask/>
      <file_required>N</file_required>
      <include_subfolders>N</include_subfolders>
    </file>
    <fields>
      <field>
        <name>odata_nextLink</name>
        <path>[&#39;@odata.nextLink&#39;]</path>
        <type>String</type>
        <format/>
        <currency/>
        <decimal/>
        <group/>
        <length>-1</length>
        <precision>-1</precision>
        <trim_type>none</trim_type>
        <repeat>N</repeat>
      </field>
    </fields>
    <limit>0</limit>
    <IsInFields>Y</IsInFields>
    <IsAFile>N</IsAFile>
    <valueField>json</valueField>
    <shortFileFieldName/>
    <pathFieldName/>
    <hiddenFieldName/>
    <lastModificationTimeFieldName/>
    <uriNameFieldName/>
    <rootUriNameFieldName/>
    <extensionFieldName/>
    <sizeFieldName/>
<attributes></attributes>
    <cluster_schema/>
    <remotesteps>
      <input>
      </input>
      <output>
      </output>
    </remotesteps>
    <GUI>
      <xloc>406</xloc>
      <yloc>175</yloc>
      <draw>Y</draw>
    </GUI>
    </step>

</steps>
<order>
    <hop>
      <from>Generate rows</from>
      <to>JSON input</to>
      <enabled>Y</enabled>
    </hop>

</order>
<notepads>
</notepads>
<step_error_handling>
</step_error_handling>
</transformation-steps>
```